# pytest: grouping tests into classes and using test fixtures

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am trying to group unit tests using classes, and reusing certain setup code - here with a pytest test fixture.  I tried to reproduce [this example](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/python/grouping-tests-with-pytest-mark).

```
import pytest
from dataliner import core


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def dl_core():
    dl_core = core.DataLinerCore()
    dl_core.boot()
    yield dl_core

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("dl_core")
class TestTrend:

    def test_with_codes(self):
        trend = self.dl_core.get_combination_trend(
            included_codes=["I130016", "I130017"],
            interval="w",
        )
```

I don't see the difference to the example, but my code fails with:

```
================================================================================ FAILURES ================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________ TestTrend.test_with_codes ________________________________________________________________________

self = <test_core.TestTrend object at 0x1a1e1cfc18>

    @pytest.mark.smoke
    def test_with_codes(self):
>       trend = self.dl_core.get_combination_trend(
            included_codes=["I130016", "I130017"],
            interval="w",
        )
E       AttributeError: 'TestTrend' object has no attribute 'dl_core'

tests/test_core.py:16: AttributeError
```

Comment: The example actually sets the `driver` attribute on the class: `request.cls.driver = driver`, that's why the tests can access `self.driver`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't spot that. I'm not sure I want to reproduce this example exactly, since all I want is to group tests and reuse a setup object - ideally without rebuilding it every time. Recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: But if you want to access `dl_core` in your classes then you have to inject it as the example shows

Comment: Using setup and teardown and pytest fixture features extensively bears the risk that you end up with what Meszaros calls 'Obscure Tests'.  Consider using descriptively named helper functions for the setup which are then called explicitly from the respective tests.